# DirectShow and the Canon EOS 5D Mark II

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, directshow, canon-sdk

Is there any way to communicate with a Canon EOS 5D Mark II (or a similar Nikon) via DirectShow, so that you can get a live-stream if the Camera is connected at the PC?

A solution would be to use the EOS-Utility or, in an own application, the Canon SDK (Nikon SDK).

So, is there a way to get a live-video from the connected camera with Microsoft DirectShow?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Canon SDK is the only option you have.
You need to sign up and be approved by Canon.
Once you have the SDK you are on your own, Canon offers no support.
http://usa.canon.com/cusa/consumer/standard_display/sdk_homepage

Here is a nice wrapper you can use as a starting point:
https://github.com/esskar/Canon.Eos.Framework

Answer (score 1):

as I know Canon doesn't provide WDM driver for its EOS series (or for any other cameras). W/o it you cannot use it as a capture source

Answer (score 0):

gPhoto2 can access this camera apparently http://gphoto.sourceforge.net/proj/libgphoto2/support.php